# Seeing different featured question numbers depending on section

Tags: bug, questions, bounty

I'm seeing different numbers for the 'featured' questions depending on what page I'm on.
If I'm on the main page the [featured](https://android.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) link shows (5)

[image: header]

But if i click on it I only see 3 questions, although it stills shows (5) in the tab.

[image: wrong]

If I'm within the [Questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured) section it shows correctly (3).
[image: correct]

Comment: Caching, I bet.